# Image on left side of radio button HTML CSS Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[I would like to place the image on the left side of radio
Here is the code

HTML:

```
          <div class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" id="cc" name="radio-button" 
                 value="0">
                <label for="cc">
                    <span><img src="images/joker.jpg"></span>
                    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                    adipiscing elit. In semper quam nunc.</span>
                </label>
            </div>
```

See the image link to view what I want to do Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVMJB.png

Comment: Then why are you using an image inside label? remove the image from the label and add it above input type.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above you need to move the `img` outside of the `label`. This is an example of your example. You may just want to vertically align the `input`

```css
.btn.btn-radio {
  border: 1px solid #333 !important;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  padding: 1em !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.left-img {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503249023995-51b0f3778ccf?auto=format&fit=crop&w=311&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
}

.right-input {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
}

label.example p {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn btn-radio">
  <div class="left-img"></div>
  <div class="right-input">
    <input type="radio" id="cc" name="radio-button" value="0" />
    <label class="example" for="cc">
          <h3>Lorem</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In semper quam nunc.</p>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the use of the image inside the label is logic. As we can click on the image to trigger the radio button, and in your case we cannot. So i think that's why he used it insde the label.

Answer (score 1):

You may put the input inside the label also and adjust your code like this:

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-default">
  <label for="cc">
     <img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
     <input type="radio" id="cc" name="radio-button" value="0">
     <div>
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
        adipiscing elit. In semper quam nunc.</p>
     </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankkyou :D Happy New year